# Filled the cell with details base on colour of other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have a excel which has the task perform by team,user will put the details of each task in each row, which will comprises date (date task started) and the other details.
Task which is complete, the particular row will highlight in green the task which is incomplete it will show in yellow and the one which is canceled will show as red. I have to make  summary table which will give be a break up of how many task completed cancelled or incomplete. I'm looking for a option to pull details base on row colour? Any option is available?

Comment: pnuts is certainly correct that color is typically used to *display* the logic of the computation rather than to being the basis of the computation. Having said that, it is certainly possible to e.g. tell what cells in a worksheet are colored green.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VBA to create a UDF (User Defined Function) and save it into an Add-In file so it can be used on every workbook and other computers.

Microsoft have a knowledge article explaining how to do this and this can be found [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2815384).
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2815384)

Basically the code to use is:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As range, criteria As range) As Long
    Dim datax As range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Now in the cell you want to count the colour for write the function: `=CountCcolor(range_data,criteria)`

The "range_data" refers to the range you want to count the amount of colours in and the "criteria" should be the cell reference of a cell the same colour that you want to count.